# how to unset a session array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, unset

I created a session array using

```
$_SESSION['create'] = array();
```

then filled out the array using this,

```
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-name']    = $_POST['new-campaign-name'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-type']    = $_POST['new-campaign-type'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-country'] = $_POST['new-campaign-country'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-list']    = $_POST['new-campaign-contact'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-des']     = $_POST['new-campaign-des'];
```

but i would want to delete all of the content of the session array.

i tried this

```
unset($_SESSION['create']);
```

but it seems to be not working and all of the values are still on the session data, is there a way to reset the contents of my session array?

Comment: Why not `$_SESSION['create'] = array();` again?

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['create'])` works to unset that particular key, if it doesn't work for you, maybe some code is adding it in again. `$_SESSION=array()` would reset the whole session.

Comment: it doesn't reset the session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to set the `create` part of the session empty again. You do this by using `$_SESSION['create'] = array();` again, as you did to initialize it.

Comment: could you please upvote Fred -ii- answer for his effort

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use the following built-in function to do so

```
session_unset();
```

[session_unset on PHP.net](http://php.net/session_unset)

Comment: i don't want to unset other sessions only that specific session array

Comment: Could you give us a larger piece of code to work with and state which version of PHP you're using?

Comment: Just a hunch, but verify that you didn't close the session for writing ( session_write_close() )  prior to unsetting the array key ( which should work ). Doing so will unset the vars for the current execution but will cause all unset session vars to return next session_start()

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tests that I ran using your existing session variables, including some of my own.

Consult the comments throughout the script.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['create'] = array();

// this one can be used also
// $_SESSION=array();

/*
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-name']    = $_POST['new-campaign-name'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-type']    = $_POST['new-campaign-type'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-country'] = $_POST['new-campaign-country'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-list']    = $_POST['new-campaign-contact'];
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-des']     = $_POST['new-campaign-des'];

$_SESSION['create_2']['new-campaign-des_2']     = $_POST['new-campaign-des_2'];

*/

// my own test without POST variables
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-name']    = 'new-campaign-name';
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-type']    = 'new-campaign-type';
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-country'] = 'new-campaign-country';
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-list']    = 'new-campaign-contact';
$_SESSION['create']['new-campaign-des']     = 'new-campaign-des';

$_SESSION['create_2']['new-campaign-des_2']     = 'new-campaign-des_2';

// echo "Session variables above this";

echo $_SESSION['create']; // this will echo Array

echo "<br>";

// this will unset all in $_SESSION['create'] group
unset($_SESSION['create']);

echo "<br>";

var_dump($_SESSION);

echo "<hr>";

// this will echo NULL
var_dump($_SESSION['create']);

echo "<hr>";

// this will echo Array even after unsetting $_SESSION['create']
echo $_SESSION['create_2'];

echo "<hr>";

// this will echo/dump
// array(1) { ["new-campaign-des_2"]=> string(18) "new-campaign-des_2" } 
var_dump($_SESSION['create_2']);

echo "<hr>";

// this will echo/dump
// array(1) { ["create_2"]=> array(1) { ["new-campaign-des_2"]=> string(18) "new-campaign-des_2" } }
// but not anything in the ['create'] group
var_dump($_SESSION);
```